# Kivy: Transfer information between screens

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I have a simple app where users have to type in username and password to access second screen. To do this I use sqlite.
***Py**

```
class LoginPage(Screen):
    def findAccount(self):
        username = self.ids["login_in"].text
        password = self.ids["pass_in"].text
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = ? AND password = ?;
                  ''', (username, password))
        records = c.fetchone() #returns (1, Bob, qwerty, bob@gmail.com, 071234556)
        return records
    def verify(self):
        try:
            records = LoginPage.findAccount(self)
            if self.ids["login_in"].text == records[1] and self.ids["pass_in"].text == records[2]:
                self.manager.current = "user"
        except TypeError:
            print("Something is not correct")

class UserInfoPage(Screen):
    def show_info(self):
        pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_file
```

***Kv**

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginPage:
    UserInfoPage:

<LoginPage>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    name: "login"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login_in
        TextInput:
            id: pass_in
            password: True
        Button:
            text: "GO"
            on_release:
                root.findAccount()
                root.verify()
<UserInfoPage>:
    name: "user"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: the_id
            text: 'id: '
        Label:
            text: 'name: '
        Label:
            text: 'email: '
        Label:
            text: 'phone number: '
```

by using 'show_info()' method I want to display user's information on 'UserInfoPage' screen. To do this I need information from variable 'records' from 'findAccount' account method. I tried to do like this:

```
def show_info(self):
    information = LoginPage.findAccount(self)
    user_id = information[0]
    self.ids["the_id"].text = self.ids["the_id"].text + str(user_id)
```

but it throws an error because 'findAccount()' method is linked to first screen. How to save information I got on first screen and transfer it on to second screen?
Thank you.

Comment: when you call show_info()?

Comment: I called it on Label:text: root.show_info(), but at that moment function was returning user_id.

Comment: The password is salted and encrypted in the actual code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we must correct certain errors:

- It is not necessary to call `findAccount()` in the `.kv` because `verify()` is calling it in the `.py`.
- The `LoginPage.findAccount(self)` statement is incorrect, you must use self directly to call it, ie the correct thing is `self.findAccount()`.
- Avoid using try and except if it is unnecessary, in your case it would only be necessary to verify that `records` is not `None`.

To add the information is not necessary to create a new method, a better approach would be to create properties and this is assigned through the screen, to get the appropriate screen we use the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager`.

***.py**

```
class LoginPage(Screen):
    def findAccount(self):
        username = self.ids["login_in"].text
        password = self.ids["pass_in"].text
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = ? AND password = ?;
                  ''', (username, password))
        records = c.fetchone() #returns (1, Bob, qwerty, bob@gmail.com, 071234556)
        return records

    def verify(self):
        records = self.findAccount()
        if records is not None:
            _id, name, password, email, phone_number = records
            if self.ids["login_in"].text == name and self.ids["pass_in"].text == password:
                user_screen = self.manager.get_screen("user")
                user_screen._id = str(_id)
                user_screen._name = name
                user_screen._email = email
                user_screen._phone_number = phone_number

                self.manager.current = "user"
            else:
                print("Something is not correct")

class UserInfoPage(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

***.kv**

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginPage:
    UserInfoPage:

<LoginPage>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    name: "login"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login_in
        TextInput:
            id: pass_in
            password: True
        Button:
            text: "GO"
            on_release:
                root.verify()

<UserInfoPage>:
    name: "user"

    _id: ""
    _name: ""
    _email: ""
    _phone_number: ""
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'id: ' + root._id
        Label:
            text: 'name: ' + root._name
        Label:
            text: 'email: ' + root._email
        Label:
            text: 'phone number: ' + root._phone_number
```

Comment: It works now, thank you! And thank you for correcting other errors